# Count running total of number of days in DataFrame and insert value into new column

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie question.

I have a data frame containing a list of dates. I want to count the number of dates and insert a running total of the number of days that have passed by row into a new column. I've gotten as far as getting a working loop that inserts the count, but it's inserting the count of the entire length of the column. I've figured out that what I'm doing is telling it to insert the length of the entire series so I know why it's going wrong, but I've run out of guesses for things to google to find the info I'm looking for.

What I have:

|  | date | day_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 669 | 2020-06-01 | 2 |
| 670 | 2020-06-02 | 2 |
| 671 | 2020-06-03 | 2 |

What I'm trying to get:

|  | date | day_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 669 | 2020-06-01 | 0 |
| 670 | 2020-06-02 | 1 |
| 671 | 2020-06-03 | 2 |

How I'm trying to do it:

```
index = 0
for row in df:
    df['day_num'] = index
    index = index + 1
```

I realize this could potentially be done by setting index values from the df extract I'm using to get the values I want that way, this is about understanding how to insert the values as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to just include a running counter you can simply do

```
df['day_num']=range(len(df))
```

output

```
    date    day_num
669 2020-06-01  0
670 2020-06-02  1
671 2020-06-03  2
```

To actually count the number of days from the first day in the dataframe, you can do

```
df['day_num']=(df['date'] - df['date'].iloc[0]).dt.days
```

(make sure 'date' column is an actual date, ie you may want to do `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` first)